# Get multiple slices of data from single MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

Ok, say I've got a collection of docs called Baz, say it looks like:

```
[
    { _id: 1, foo: true, bar: true },
    { _id: 2, foo: false, bar: true },
    { _id: 3, foo: true, bar: false },
    { _id: 1, foo: false, bar: false }
]
```

I want to query it and get results like this:

```
[
    { isFoo: [
        { _id: 1, foo: true, bar: true },
        { _id: 3, foo: true, bar: false }
    ], isBar: [
        { _id: 1, foo: true, bar: true },
        { _id: 2, foo: false, bar: true }
    ]}
]
```

As you can see, it gives me an array of all the documents that have `foo: true` and also a list of all the documents that have `bar: true`. That's what I want to end up with! Thanks in advance, SO community!

### In sum

What query can be written against Baz to get the desired results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `$facet` operator provides almost **exactly** what you seek, the only difference being with `$facet` you will get back a single doc from `aggregate()` with two fields of arrays:

```
{
    "isFoo" : [
       {  "_id" : 1,  "foo" : true,  "bar" : true  },
       {  "_id" : 3,  "foo" : true,  "bar" : false  }
    ],
    "isBar" : [
       {  "_id" : 1,  "foo" : true,  "bar" : true },
       {  "_id" : 2,  "foo" : false, "bar" : true }
    ]
}


db.baz.aggregate([
  {$facet: {
    "isFoo": [
      {$match: {"foo": true}}
      ]
    ,"isBar": [
      {$match: {"bar": true}}
      ]
   }}
 ]);
```